# AddThis with Vue shares wrong links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addthis

So I have a page that uses AddThis for link sharing and Vue for rendering. Now, the page displays a list of links with multiple pages. On the first page all sharing works as expected, but on the second page, it uses the links from the first page.

An example to reproduce this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pages: [
      [{
        url: 'http://google.com',
        title: 'Google'
      }],
      [{
        url: 'http://yahoo.com',
        title: 'Yahoo'
      }]
    ],
    currentPage: 0
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.pages[this.currentPage]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchPage() {
      if (this.currentPage === 0) {
        this.currentPage = 1;
      } else {
        this.currentPage = 0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="sharer" v-for="item in items">
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" :data-url="item.url" :data-title="item.title">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <button @click="switchPage">Switch pages</button>
</div>

<script src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57f620a4f185d54b"></script>
```

When on the first page, AddThis correctly shares the Google homepage. But when on the second page, it doesn't pick up the `data-*` tags for sharing Yahoo.

Note: You can't really run the StackOverflow snippet here because AddThis wants to access cookies which the sandboxed iframe forbids. A running version can also be found at https://jsfiddle.net/d1az3qb3/3/. Please remember to disable ad-blockers to let AddThis load.

### What I already tried

- Running `addthis.layers.refresh()` after switching pags
- Running `addthis.toolbox('.addthis_inline_share_toolbox')`

(Both directly and in `this.$nextTick(() => …)`)

### Question

Is AddThis just broken, is it incompatible with Vue or is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of digging into this, it seems to work after destroying and re-initializing all AddThis layers (using the SmartLayer API) like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pages: [
      [{
        url: 'http://google.com',
        title: 'Google'
      }],
      [{
        url: 'http://yahoo.com',
        title: 'Yahoo'
      }]
    ],
    currentPage: 0
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.pages[this.currentPage]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchPage() {
      if (this.currentPage === 0) {
        this.currentPage = 1;
      } else {
        this.currentPage = 0;
      }

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        // The interesting bit:
        const destroyLayers = layers => layers.destroy();
        destroyLayers.pi = true;  // Somehow needed by AddThis

        addthis.layers(destroyLayers);
        addthis.layers.refresh();
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="sharer" v-for="item in items">
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_ctwk" :data-url="item.url" :data-title="item.title">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <button @click="switchPage">Switch pages</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57f620a4f185d54b"></script>
```

For a completely functional JSFiddle, see https://jsfiddle.net/msiemens/82ysztk9/1/

Comment: This doesn't work (including the jsfiddle), possibly there have been some changes by addthis.

Comment: Have spent hours on this. Nothing else worked but adding "The Interesting bit" of code above worked. Only one problem. The entire screen gives a small bump when it's used. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is an issue with `AddThis` I suggest that you render all the link and use the v-show to hide links your are not interested.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pages: [
      {
        url: 'http://google.com',
        title: 'Google',
        id: 1
      },
      {
        url: 'http://yahoo.com',
        title: 'Yahoo',
        id: 2
      }
    ],
    currentPage: 0
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItem() {
      return this.pages[this.currentPage].id
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchPage() {
      if (this.currentPage === 0) {
        this.currentPage = 1;
      } else {
        this.currentPage = 0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="sharer" v-for="item in pages">
    <div v-show="item.id === selectedItem" class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" :data-url="item.url" :data-title="item.title">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <button @click="switchPage">Switch pages</button>
</div>

<script src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57f620a4f185d54b"></script>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this requires all links to be rendered during initialization and won't work if some items are loaded dynamically, is that correct?

Comment: Dynamically changing the pages array is not an issue with vuejs. The array is reactive as long as you use method like push/slice/... If that does not work then the issue is probably due to  AddThis. Try it out and let us know. Update your question if require.

Comment: Yep, the issue is with AddThis. If the array changes, they only remember the position and take the old data instead of the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely happy with a solution that refreshes all the addThis elements on the page. For anyone that's looking for a clean solution there is an API for constructing your own addThis buttons here https://www.addthis.com/academy/addthis-core-share-follow-api/

You could implement it with something like.

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      bindAddThis() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          window.addthis.share({
            container_selector: ".content--sharing-icons",
            button_selector: ".addthis_share_button"
          });
        });
      }
    },
    afterUpdate() {
      this.bindAddThis();
    },
    mounted() {
      this.bindAddThis();
    }
  };
</script>
```

Sadly the addThis API doesn't take an element as a selector so you can't use `$refs`.